# bootstrap how to prevent sidebar collapse or disappear when viewpoint under 768px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap class `side-nav` and `nav-sidebar` to make a side navigation bar. But the issue is when the viewpoint is under 768px, the side navigation bar is disappear.

Here is my html code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar side-nav">
        <li><a href="{{ path('new_message') }}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-file brl-sidebar-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="New post"></a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ path('get_schedule') }}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar brl-sidebar-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Schedule"></a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ path('get_task') }}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-saved brl-sidebar-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tasks"></a></li>
</ul>
```

I tried to change the media css code: initially, the `nav-sidebar` css code is like:  `@media (min-width: 768px)`

and I have tried to change it to min-width: 360px, but it still disappear, when the viewpoint is under 768px.

How should I do to keep the sidebar there whatever the width of the viewpoint is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bootstrap v3 doesn't have any `side-nav` or `nav-sidebar` classes...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what specific rule Bootstrap applies but it could be applying one of the bootstrap classes which are assigned to hide things either in the CSS or could be adding it with javascript.  If you can't find it, you could always overwrite it by defining your own CSS style and assigning it display:block!important; and then overright it with a new media query also with the !important tag.  As long as the CSS isn't inline that should trump whatever Bootstrap is doing.

Or if you know what class Bootstrap is applying you can remove it $('nav').removeClass('hidden');

Answer (score 0):

768px is still bigger than 320px, so you would have to either

1) Delete the media query (I would do this)
or
2) Make it (max-width: 320px)